# React Native get Android intent on application start

Tags: android, android-intent, react-native

I am working on custom React Native push notifications solution. I need to send an event to JS when app gets opened from push notification (local). To do so I added a flag to notification intent's extras and now I need to get this intent.

I tried to use `getCurrentActivity()` from Module constructor but it always returns `null`. I've been trying to find lifecycle methods to override, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: got any solution for this??